# Cannot fetch Checkmarx results to SonarQube

Tags: atlassian-crowd

I try to transfer Checkmarx results to SonarQube using the respective SonarQube pluign. But during the sonar analysis I constantly get the error message:

```
10:50:46.378 INFO: Sensor Import Checkmarx scan results to SonarQube [checkmarx]
10:50:46.379 INFO: - [CHECKMARX] - Retrieving Checkmarx scan results for current module [Checkmarx plugin version: 8.90.0]
10:50:46.379 INFO: - [CHECKMARX] - Getting Checkmarx configuration data from sonar Database.
10:50:46.379 INFO: Sensor Import Checkmarx scan results to SonarQube [checkmarx] (done) | time=1ms
10:50:46.379 ERROR: - [CHECKMARX] - NOTE: Checkmarx scan is canceled;
Error while retrieving Checkmarx settings from sonar Database.
Please make sure Checkmarx credentials are configured. [Checkmarx plugin version: 8.90.0]
```

Even with verbose and Trace logs I cannot get more details. I have configured the Checkmarx connection in the SonarQube WebUI and the connection is working fine there.

Does anybod has an idea?

We use SonarQube Version 7.9.1 (build 27448) and Checkmarx 8.9.0 HF5

Comment: Any update about this issue ?

Comment: The Checkmarx SonarQube plugin supports only SonarQube 6.3 - 6.7.x as you can read [here](https://checkmarx.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/KC/pages/169246832/CxSAST+SonarQube+Plugin+v8.5.0+and+up) They are working on a newer version AFAIK but currently there is nothing available.